# property concerning singular matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

prove that if $A$ is a singular matrix,then there exists a nonzero matrix $S$ s.t. $SA=AS=0$

I think if we can prove that for any singular matrix $T$,we can find a natural number n such that $T^{n}=0$. But I don't know how to prove that.

Comment: Singular matrices need not be nilpotent. As for your question, think in null spaces...

Comment: Do you want to require that $S\neq0$? And should "$A$" be "$T$" instead?

Comment: $$\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&0\cr}$$ is singular, but no power of it is zero.

Comment: @stewbasic I've corrected the mistake in my question.

Comment: Hint: imagine for the moment that $A$ has rank $n-1$.  Then the null space has dimension $1$ so all matrices satisfying $AS = 0$ have a certain form.  Similarly all matrices satisfying $SA = 0$ have a certain form.  There is only one matrix (up to scalar multiplication) that is simultaneously in both of these forms: find it.  Now notice that the same idea works in the general case without the uniqueness.